# How do I make both a button-click and a Enter key cause the same event?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm a newbie with JavaScript, so please bear with me. I am doing a To-Do List app which requires the user to enter a text in the text box and the item would be added when a button is clicked or when you it the Enter Key. I was able to do it with the Button Click and when I added the functionality for the Enter key, the button stopped working. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Below is the java script code I have. Thank You.

```
var itemTextBox, newButton;

function addNewItem(list, itemText)
{
    var listItem;

    listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = itemText;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

itemTextBox = document.getElementById("inputText");
itemTextBox.focus();
newButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
newButton.onclick = userInput();

itemTextBox.onkeyup = function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13)
    {
        userInput();
        itemTextBox.value = '';
    }
};

function userInput()
{
    var itemText;

    itemText = itemTextBox.value;
    if (itemText || itemText !== "")
    {
        addNewItem(document.getElementById("listOfItems"), itemText);
    }
}
```

Comment: `newButton.onclick = userInput;` (no parens)

Comment: i think you have a problem with curly braces in your code

Comment: the removal of parenthesis did the job